# Web.Release.Config Rewrite URL Exclusion

Tags: iis-7, web-config

I have found the following code which will redirect all my traffic to https:

```
<system.webServer>
<rewrite xdt:Transform="Insert">
  <rules>
    <rule name="RedirectToHTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{SERVER_NAME}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Is it possible to add an "exclusion" to this rule somehow?

I would like a particular path not to be redirected if possible

For example I would like everything below http://www.example.com/desktopmodules/ not to redirect.

Can it be done please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a rule above it which matches your exclusion pattern, ensuring that the `stopProcessing="true"` is set on the rule, but with no action:

```
<system.webServer>
<rewrite xdt:Transform="Insert">
  <rules>

    <!-- Prevent redirection of URLs matching this pattern -->
    <rule name="ExcludeRedirectToHTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^desktopmodules.*" />
      <action type="None"  />
    </rule>

    <rule name="RedirectToHTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{SERVER_NAME}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```